# Create a VBA program that will perform an addition or subtraction of two Hexadecimal numbers

Tags: excel, vba, userform, addition, subtraction

I'm trying to get both addition and subtraction options to work and display the proper symbol between each label box. I've been running into an error, which VBA highlights for me. The boxes A, B, and C need to be valued at 10, 11, and 12. When you click a box it's supposed to populate the first empty box with the value. When both boxes are full and you click another letter, its should not be changed, instead the values will be locked until you hit clear.

**Current code:**

```
Private Sub Addition_Click()
Me.Result = (Me.LblFirstNum + 0) + (Me.LblSecondNum + 0)
'lblresult = Val(LblFirstNum) + Val(LblSecondNum)
End Sub

Private Sub BtnA_Click()
    With LblFirstNum
        'to display text
        .Caption = "10"
        .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
        'wrap text
        .WordWrap = True
        .Font.Size = 18
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub BtnB_Click()
    With LblSecondNum
        'to display text
        .Caption = "11"
        .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
        'wrap text
        .WordWrap = True
        .Font.Size = 18
    End With 
End Sub

Private Sub BtnC_Click()
    With LblSecondNum
        'to display text
        .Caption = "12"
        .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
        'wrap text
        .WordWrap = True
        .Font.Size = 18
    End With
End Sub



Private Sub Calculate_Click()
    'Me.Result = (Me.LblFirstNum + 0) + (Me.LblSecondNum + 0)
    lblresult.Value = Val(LblFirstNum.Value) + Val(LblSecondNum.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub Clear_Click()
    Unload UserForm1
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    'Exit Command
    UserForm1.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub Result_Change()
End Sub

Private Sub Label4_Click()  
End Sub

Private Sub LblFirstNum_Click()
End Sub

Private Sub LblSecondNum_Click()
End Sub

Private Sub LblSign_Click()
End Sub

Private Sub Subtraction_Click()
    'Me.Result = (Me.LblFirstNum + 0) - (Me.LblSecondNum + 0)
    lblresult.Value = Val(LblFirstNum.Value) - Val(LblSecondNum.Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: the error i keep getting is Compile Error: method or data member not found

Comment: Which line do you get that error on?

Comment: Private Sub Addition_Click() , Private Sub Calculate_Click(), Private Sub Subtraction_Click() are highlighted in yellow. and "LblSecondNum" which is the second label box, is highlighted in blue in each instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Calculate_Click()` and `Subtraction_Click()`, you've tried to retrieve the text shown on a label using `LblFirstNum.Value` and `LblSecondNum.Value`. Labels don't have a "Value" property. The correct property to use is "Caption".

In `Addition_Click()`, it's unclear whether `Result` is the correct name for the control you're trying to reference. Elsewhere in this code, you have `lblresult` so you should establish which is the correct name and use that throughout.

You may also want to check the use of [Unload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/unload-statement) in `Clear_Click()` (assuming that `UserForm1` is the form we are working with). Your current code will probably result in an automation error on the `UserForm1.Show` line

Comment: Thank you! i will try that. i have not had a problem with the Clear function. i need it to just clear the captions in the labels when i click it and it works fine so far. thank you for your help